# Codeigniter model can not connect to db

Tags: codeigniter-2

My controller can connect to the DB but my model can not. I have autoloaded the DB in the autoload.php file, but no luck in the model.

so if I do something like 
$this->db->insert('table', $data);

I receive this *Call to a member function insert() on a non-object*  I have used Codeigniter before but have never had this issue, on my other project I did not even use parent::__construct()

```
class Bucketlist extends CI_Model {

private $data = array();

public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
}

// Setter Function
public function __set ($var, $val) {
    $this->data[$var] = $val;
}

// Getter Function
public function __get($var) {
    return (isset($this->data[$var])) ? $this->data[$var] : null;
}

// Create WishList
function createBucketList($bucketlist) {
    $this->db->insert('_bucketlist', $bucketlist->data);
}
```

}

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to Autoload the Database connection (http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/connecting.html), as it appears that the db variable is not instantiated before you are trying to use it.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that and I get this response.
Call to a member function database() on a non-object

Comment: I stripped out the magic function __set and __get and it now connects. I'm not a full time PHPer, but I have no idea why this would cause an issue.

Comment: @Matt - please post your solution as an answer and accept it when the system allows. This way, your post will stop showing up in "unanswered" lists. Thanks!